# Python, How to terminate a "shell=True" subprocess after execution

Tags: python, subprocess

I am executing the following command in a python script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import shlex
import os
import subprocess
import string
import random
import signal



pro = subprocess.Popen("zcat production_dump_2013-09-16_12-00.sql.gz | PGPASSWORD=everything psql -d voylla_solr -h localhost -p 5432 -U nishant", shell=True)
pro.wait()
os.kill(pro.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

This gives me:

```
OSError: [Errno 3] No such process
```

I also tried using

```
pro = subprocess.Popen("zcat production_dump_2013-09-16_12-00.sql.gz | PGPASSWORD=everything psql -d voylla_solr -h localhost -p 5432 -U nishant", shell=True)
pro.wait()
pro.kill()
```

and this gives me:

```
OSError: [Errno 3] No such process
```

How do I kill the process after execution to execute next commands

Answer (score 1):

[`Popen.wait`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) waits for the process to terminate, so there is nothing left to kill once it returns.

Once a process exits, you're not supposed to "kill it". The only thing you're supposed to do is collect its return code, which `Popen.wait` does for you.